# User Richtext with TextSpan in container but is not its not gives proper output

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-textformfield, flutter-material

I used RichText and TextSpan for my formatted string.
But issue is I want long string with ... form

I do some RnD, As per some solutions on google I use ***Expanded and Flexible*** widget also but not get output even when i user Expanded or Flexible string will be vanished.

Screenshot of what I want,

[image]

And Screenshot of my output

[image]

Instead of long string with ... at the end within a container, The string overlapping the container and show that UI warning

My Code is

```
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Visibility(
                  visible: notificationList[index].isHeader ? false : true,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                        1, notificationList[index].isHeader ? 0 : 15, 1, 0),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          blurRadius: 3,
                          offset: Offset(0, 0), // Shadow position
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 40,
                          height: 40,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 15, 0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                            border:
                                Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.directions_car_outlined,
                              color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Flexible(
                                child: RichText(
                                    softWrap: true,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    text: TextSpan(
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15.0,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                      children: <TextSpan>[
                                        TextSpan(
                                            text:
                                                '${notificationList[index].title}',
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                        TextSpan(
                                            text:
                                                ' (${notificationList[index].name})'),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flexible widget has to be the first child of the row for it to identify how much it will extend and remove the softwrap so there is no line break. I also removed the columns and left only the visibility.

```
Visibility(
  visible: notificationList[index].isHeader ? false : true,
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
        1, notificationList[index].isHeader ? 0 : 15, 1, 0),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      color: Colors.white,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.grey,
          blurRadius: 3,
          offset: Offset(0, 0), // Shadow position
        ),
      ],
    ),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 40,
          height: 40,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 15, 0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
            border:
            Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.directions_car_outlined,
              color: Color(0xfff2426d),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
            child: RichText(
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                text: TextSpan(
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                        text:
                        '${notificationList[index].title}',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    TextSpan(
                        text:
                        ' (${notificationList[index].name})'),
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You use flexible in wrong widget, you should wrap one of the widget in row with expanded or flexible, like this:

```
Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(1, 15, 1, 0),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          blurRadius: 3,
                          offset: Offset(0, 0), // Shadow position
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 40,
                          height: 40,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 15, 0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                            border:
                                Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.directions_car_outlined,
                              color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: RichText(
                                softWrap: true,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                text: TextSpan(
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  children: <TextSpan>[
                                    TextSpan(
                                        text: 'New York To - Los Angeles',
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    TextSpan(text: ' Mickle Jaco'),
                                  ],
                                )),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: @DevDhande did my answer help you or you were looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can run this code

```dart
     Column(
        children: [
        Visibility(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                1, 15, 1, 0),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  blurRadius: 3,
                  offset: Offset(0, 0), // Shadow position
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 40,
                  height: 40,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 15, 0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                    border:
                    Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.directions_car_outlined,
                      color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: Flexible(
                          child: RichText(
                              softWrap: true,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              text: TextSpan(
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                children: <TextSpan>[
                                  TextSpan(
                                      text:'New York[enter image description here][1] To - Los Angeles',
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  TextSpan(
                                      text:
                                      ' (New York To - Los Angeles)'),
                                ],
                              )),
                        ),
                      ),
    
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ],
        ),
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Remove Flexible widget:-**

```
 child: Flexible(
   child: RichText(/..),
 )
```